# How to properly set datagridview defaultcellstyle using cellstyle builder format string dialog?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

[image: My Screenshot]

I want to set my datagridview defaultcellstyle to currency format rupiah using cellstyle builder but i don't know how to properly put my code in this custom format. I know the code, but when i put in it, the result is wrong.

here is the code:

```
ItemDataGridView.Columns(9).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "Rp ###,###"
```

I can apply this code inside datagridview cell formatting and it works, but i wanted to put this code inside datagridview properties instead inside my form.vb.

Comment: Did you try putting the format string from your code into the field in that dialogue?

Comment: `dim culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("id-ID") ItemDataGridView.Columns(9).DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = culture ItemDataGridView.Columns(9).DefaultCellStyle.Format = $"C{culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits}"`

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes I want to put my code inside that field dialogue. I just want to take advantage of what visual studio provide us instead type my code in the cell_formatting handler.

Comment: That's not an answer to my question. I didn't ask what you want to do. I asked whether you did something specific. You've posted some code that contains a format string and you have posted a screenshot that shows a field for a format string. Have you put the format string you have into that field? If not, why not? If so, what happened?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Oh sorry, I already did put my string code inside that dialogue, but the results are every cells in that column becomes that string.